# Copy a channel from one image to another using safe code

Tags: c#, gdi+

I'm trying to refactor this unsafe code to copy a single ARGB channel from one image to another using `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy` as per this example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ey6h79d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but I'm totally lost.

Could anyone walk me through how I would go about it?

```
public enum ChannelARGB
{
    Blue = 0,
    Green = 1,
    Red = 2,
    Alpha = 3
}

public static void transferOneARGBChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother(
    Bitmap source,
    Bitmap dest,
    ChannelARGB sourceChannel,
    ChannelARGB destChannel )
{
    if ( source.Size!=dest.Size )
        throw new ArgumentException();
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle( Point.Empty, source.Size );
    BitmapData bdSrc = source.LockBits( r, 
                                        ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, 
                                        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    BitmapData bdDst = dest.LockBits( r, 
                                      ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                      PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb );
    unsafe
    {
        byte* bpSrc = (byte*)bdSrc.Scan0.ToPointer();
        byte* bpDst = (byte*)bdDst.Scan0.ToPointer();
        bpSrc += (int)sourceChannel;
        bpDst += (int)destChannel;
        for ( int i = r.Height * r.Width; i > 0; i-- )
        {
            *bpDst = *bpSrc;
            bpSrc += 4;
            bpDst += 4;
        }
    }
    source.UnlockBits( bdSrc );
    dest.UnlockBits( bdDst );
}
```

## Edit

In an attempt to work through @Ben Voigt walk though I have come up with this so far. Unfortunately I am now getting the following error:

> Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is corrupt.

```
    private static void TransferOneArgbChannelFromOneBitmapToAnother(
                                         Bitmap source,
                                         Bitmap destination, 
                                         ChannelARGB sourceChannel, 
                                         ChannelARGB destinationChannel)
    {
        if (source.Size != destination.Size)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, source.Size);

        // Lockbits the source.
        BitmapData bitmapDataSource = source.LockBits(rectangle,
                                                  ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                  PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap.
        int bytes = bitmapDataSource.Stride * bitmapDataSource.Height;

        // Allocate a buffer for the source image
        byte[] sourceRgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptrSource = bitmapDataSource.Scan0;

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptrSource, 
                                                    sourceRgbValues, 
                                                    0, 
                                                    bytes);

        // Unlockbits the source.
        source.UnlockBits(bitmapDataSource);

        // Lockbits the destination.
        BitmapData bitmapDataDestination = destination.LockBits(rectangle,
                                                  ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                                                  PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        // Allocate a buffer for image
        byte[] destinationRgbValues = new byte[bytes];

        IntPtr ptrDestination = bitmapDataDestination.Scan0;

        // Copy the RGB values into the array.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptrDestination,
                                                    destinationRgbValues, 
                                                    0, 
                                                    bytes);

        ptrSource += (int)sourceChannel;
        ptrDestination += (int)destinationChannel;

        for (int i = rectangle.Height * rectangle.Width; i > 0; i--)
        {
            destinationRgbValues[i] = sourceRgbValues[i];
            ptrSource += 4;
            ptrDestination += 4;
        }

        // Copy the RGB values back to the bitmap
        // ******This is where I am getting the exception*******.
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(destinationRgbValues, 
                                                    0, 
                                                    ptrDestination, 
                                                    bytes);

        // Unlock bits the destination.
        destination.UnlockBits(bitmapDataDestination);
    }
```

Can anyone see what I have done wrong? This is all a bit over my head to be honest. I think I should buy some books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `LockBits` the source.
2. `Marshal.Copy` the source `BitmapData` to a `byte[]` buffer.
3. `UnlockBits` the source.
4. `LockBits` the destination.
5. `Marshal.Copy` the destination `BitmapData` to a `byte[]` buffer.
6. Loop through and copy that channel from the source `byte[]` to the destination `byte[]` (note, use arithmetic on indexes instead of on pointers)
7. `Marshal.Copy` the destination `byte[]` back to the `BitmapData`.
8. `UnlockBits` the destination.

I'm not sure what the point is, though.  Code that uses `Marshal.Copy` is just as dangerous as code that uses the `unsafe` keyword, and should require similar code security permission.

A potentially more efficient way would be to use `ImageAttributes.SetColorMatrix` to remove the desired channel from the destination image, remove all other channels from the source image, and then blend.  See the example for [`ColorMatrix`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix)

Or use DirectX (or OpenGL) and a shader that just transfers the one channel.

Comment: Just following your guidelines now. The reason I'm looking to do this is so that I can use the code in medium trust on a server. The `ColorMatrix` idea seems interesting.

Comment: @James: `Marshal.Copy` isn't allowed in medium trust, is it?  Anything you can do with `unsafe` code can be done with `Marshal.Copy`.

Comment: I've added a what code I have come up with so far following your instructions to my question but I can't seem to get it working. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: @James: You need to pass `bitmapDataDestination.Scan0`.  You've changed `ptrDestination` several times, it's no longer the correct pointer.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense and solved that error. My code doesn't produce the same result as the unsafe original.Sad times.

Comment: @James: You're not updating the array indexes the way the old code updated the pointers, that's the problem.  Get rid of `ptrSource` and `ptrDestination` (or use them only for `Marshal.Copy`), instead write `int s = sourceChannel, d = destinationChannel; for (...) { destination[d] = source[s]; d+=4; s+=4; }`

Comment: Ah! that makes sense now! Thank you! If I could upvote an answer more than once I would most certainly do that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use my simple LINQ based image processing framework from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/linqimageprocessing) or [Codeplex](http://codeblocks.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Linq%20Image%20Processing%20sample&referringTitle=Home) and write a simple query that swaps the channels around.

You could also use a ColorMatrix to perform the channel swap like in [this](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop3d/MonoGame.Framework/Graphics/ImageEx.cs) code.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a ColorMatrix won't work if you want to combine channels from two separate images. You would need an additive (or bitwise or) blending method, and the only blending provided by GDI+ is Over and Copy. It also looks to me like any methods that would allow you to access the bits directly, including LockBits, are locked down.

I think the only option is to use GetPixel and SetPixel on each pixel, something like this:

```
Color dstColor = bpDst.GetPixel(x, y);
Color srcColor = bpSrc.GetPixel(x, y);
int srcValue = (srcColor.ToArgb() >> (sourceChannel * 8)) & 0xff;
int dstArgb = (dstColor.ToArgb() & ~(0xff << (destChannel * 8))) | (srcValue << (destChannel * 8));
bpDst.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(dstArgb));
```

Comment: Doesn't blending occur when an alpha channel is present?  Oh, but that'll also blend the other channels.  :(  GDI had raster operation codes, can't imagine why GDI+ removed such a fundamental capability.

Comment: Blending is also controlled by the Graphics.CompositingMode property. If you're drawing a bitmap with an alpha channel, SourceOver will be slower than SourceCopy. If the intent is to completely replace what's in the target, SourceCopy will be best.